# Menu Icon for Side Navigation

Tags: javascript, html

The menu icon opens a side navigation on click and the icon turns into a "X". On second click I would like it to close the side navigation and turn back to normal menu icon.

I have the code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.sidenav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #111;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
    padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidenav a {
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
    color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 25px;
    font-size: 36px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

#main {
    transition: margin-left .5s;
    padding: 16px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
}

.container {
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.bar1, .bar2, .bar3 {
    width: 35px;
    height: 5px;
    background-color: #333;
    margin: 6px 0;
    transition: 0.4s;
}

.change .bar1 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px) ;
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px) ;
}

.change .bar2 {opacity: 0;}

.change .bar3 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px) ;
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px) ;
}

</style>

</head>
<body>

<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <a href="#">Services</a>
  <a href="#">Clients</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
</div>

<div id="main">
  <div class="container" style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav(); myFunction(this)">
        <div class="bar1"></div>
        <div class="bar2"></div>
        <div class="bar3"></div>
</div>
</div>

<script>
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
}

function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft= "0";
}

function myFunction(x) {
    x.classList.toggle("change");
}


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

It currently opens the side nav fine but I am not sure how to tell it to close the side nav on second click, or where to put my closeNav() funtion.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You could use jQuery's `toggleClass()` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dislike adding JQuery if it is not already in use...You can do this just by checking the state of the menu.

```
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <a href="#">Services</a>
  <a href="#">Clients</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
</div>

<div id="main">
  <div class="container" style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="toggleMenu(this)">
        <div class="bar1"></div>
        <div class="bar2"></div>
        <div class="bar3"></div>
</div>
</div>

<script>
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
}

function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft= "0";
}

function toggleMenu(x) {
    x.classList.toggle("change");
    if(document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width > "1px"){
    closeNav();
    } else {
    openNav();
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: It worked perfectly! Thank you sooooooo much! I am new to js and everything feels like magic... Really appreciate it for taking the time to answer such a basic question.

Comment: @Vera Glad I could help! JS is a great and logical language, and it can pave the way to many others. If my post helped you, I'd appreciate it if you marked it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a class toggle. One class could be the menu closed with the `x` icon and when you toggle the other class, you can just specify the opposite.

```js
document.getElementById('menu').addEventListener('click', function () {
  if (this.classList.contains('open')) {
   this.classList.remove('open');
  } else {
   this.classList.add('open');
  }
});
```

```css
#menu {
 background:red;
 width:100px;
 height:200px;
}


#menu.open {
width:250px;
background:blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
 <p>click me!</p>
</div>
```